# Bootstrap / Angular js responsive grid with comment dropout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi i'm struggling to find a responsive grid system that works with bootstrap / angular.js

I've been using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) But when i try to drop out comments resizing the height of my div it breaks. On the developers site say this isn't supported.

Could anyone recommend anything else to use... i know this is a very specific question but i'm completely stuck.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by comment dropout, but if you're not using a container-fluid, bootstrap should work fine with Masonry.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#posts").masonry({
        itemSelector: '.post',
        isAnimated: true,
        columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {

            // do nothing for browsers with no media query support
            // .container will always be 940px
            if($(".container").width() == 940) {
                return 240;
            }   

            var width = $(window).width();
            var col = 300;

            if(width &lt; 1200 &amp;&amp; width &gt;= 980) {
                col = 240;
            }
            else if(width &lt; 980 &amp;&amp; width &gt;= 768) {
                col = 186;
            }

            return col;
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mWtmY/288/

Comment: Sorry so what i mean, is if the user clicks on one of the divs thats being arranged by masonry i would like that selected div to expand its height to reveal text.